# randomly get FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File does not exist

Tags: python, openfiledialog

I'v created a loop on python 3.7 that go to 20 directories and create a copy of a .txt file as a .csv file.

post compilation, i'm getting the error on random directories, while on other directories the loop does what i want

the code is (im using Microsoft):

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from os import path
import os

source_folder = "All Data"
for i in range(1, 21):
    mid_folder1 = "DD" + str(i)
    mid_folder2 = "MindWare"
    file_name = "DD" + str(i) + '.txt'
    full_path = os.path.join(source_folder, mid_folder1, mid_folder2, file_name)
    if path.isfile(full_path):
        df = pd.read_csv(full_path, sep="\t")
        df.to_csv(os.path.join(source_folder, mid_folder1, mid_folder2, "DD" + str(i) + '.txt'))
        print("DD" + str(i) + " is successfully CSVed")
    else:
        print("Cannot find DD" + str(i) + " file!")
```

and the output i'm receiving is:

```
DD1 is successfully CSVed
Cannot find DD2 file!
Cannot find DD3 file!
DD4 is successfully CSVed
Cannot find DD5 file!
Cannot find DD6 file!
DD7 is successfully CSVed
Cannot find DD8 file!
Cannot find DD9 file!
Cannot find DD10 file!
Cannot find DD11 file!
DD12 is successfully CSVed
DD13 is successfully CSVed
Cannot find DD14 file!
Cannot find DD15 file!
Cannot find DD16 file!
Cannot find DD17 file!
Cannot find DD18 file!
Cannot find DD19 file!
Cannot find DD20 file!
```

This is very strange because all the DD1-DD20 directories are neighbors and all of the are inside the "All data" directory

i've used os.path.join to solve this issue with no success
and i'm realize with the Microsoft backslash/forwardslash issue

if i will remove fail massage "Cannot find DDX file!" i will get the error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File "file path" does not exist

Comment: I think the problem is that there are no files: DD2.txt, DD3.txt, DD5.txt inside the mentioned folders

Comment: but there is a file, i obviously checked it

Comment: Wierd! No worries. Can you paste the output of "os.listdir(os.path.join(source_folder, mid_folder1, mid_folder2))"?

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'All Data\\DD20\\MindWare'

Comment: I made an edit to my answer. Can you give me the output of it? Thanks

Comment: The output is huge (because there is a lot of files and directories), but the output does contains the folders i want but cant reach through code

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from os import path
import os

source_folder = "All Data"
for i in range(1, 21):
    mid_folder1 = "DD" + str(i)
    mid_folder2 = "MindWare"
    file_name = "DD" + str(i) + '.txt'
    full_path = os.path.join(source_folder, mid_folder1, mid_folder2, file_name)
    if path.exists(full_path):  # check is file exists
        df = pd.read_csv(full_path, sep="\t")
        df.to_csv(os.path.join(source_folder, mid_folder1, mid_folder2, "DD" + str(i) + '.txt'))
        print("DD" + str(i) + " is successfully CSVed")
    else:
        print("File: " + full_path + " does not exist!")
```

It basically checks if the file exists or not. A slightly different version from yours

Cheers!

EDIT:
To debug, can you try the following:

```
import os
source_folder = "All Data"
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(source_folder):
    for name in files:
        print(os.path.join(path, name))
```

This is to understand the file structure

Comment: same result different output :(